# SQL query to get table name from where data are originated

Tags: sql

I have this query whch is executed on several tables of the same DB all structured in the same way.
Basically the query found out codes listed in Table_xxx,  that are not present in table "Components".

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Description,  a.Quantity FROM Table_321 AS a
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
                        UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Description, a.Quantity FROM Table_333 AS a
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
                        UNION ALL
                        .............
                        .............
                        order by Code
```

How can I get also the table name from which the "Code, Description and Quantity" are originally contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a extra column `tableName` in each select query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Description,  a.Quantity, 'Table_321' as tableName FROM Table_321 AS a
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
                        UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Description, a.Quantity, 'Table_333' as tableName FROM Table_333 AS a
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Components where Components.Code = a.Code)
                        UNION ALL
                        .............
                        .............
                        order by Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Writedown your query in below format:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Code, a.Description,  a.Quantity,'Table_321' AS tblName FROM Table_321 AS a 
WHERE a.Code NOT IN (SELECT Components.Code FROM Components)
```